# User matching algorithm implementation with wordpress and FQSM

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I'm currently working on a platform that would enable people to answer questions and to have a one-one chat with the people that match their answers.Ideally the users would be able to see the users with the most compatibility, add them , and if they accept be able to chat with them.
To try to build all that i started with a wordpress site using buddypress for the social part , and the FSQM addon (http://ipanelthemes.com/fsqm-doc/) to publish the questions.

I need a page where the the users with the most compatibility (same answers to questions)will be shown along with there compatibility score.
I have the logic to match user , how can i implement it ?

I don't know where to start . Should i use a javascript or php to code this page ?
what should my code look like ?

Any idea or suggestion is welcome . I'm pretty lost here and don't know where to start.

Tank you for your help ! :)